# Are there disadvantages to using Full-Text Search in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Are there disadvantages to using Full-Text Search in SQL Server? Is there much of an increased CPU or memory load on the server?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Full text has been rewritten a couple of times over the years and the version you are using matters a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Read this: [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc917695).